# Making my discord bot listen for specific messages and answer back when it identifies one

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, I'm new to python and even more to coding bots on discord. At the moment I'm using discord.py and red-bot (https://docs.discord.red/en/stable/index.html).

At the moment I'm trying to make the bot listen to a new message and print something in response to it, but I just can't figure it out. Since I'm using red-bot I didn't go through the steps of using `client = discord.Client()` and setting a token on the code itself so using `@client.event()` doesn't seem to work, nor `@bot.event()`, and I can't really find any other way to make the bot listen for an `on_message()` event.

Edit with part of my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from redbot.core import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):

    client = discord.Client()

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@bot.event()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if 'test' in message.content:
            await self.send_message(message.channel, 'it works!')
```

Console returns that bot in `@bot.event()` is not defined.

Also a separate initialization file, it's done this way to follow Red's guide of how to make a cog.

```py
from .remind import MyCog


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Comment: Why are you using red bot

Comment: It has other cogs that I use, and it seemed like a good starting point to code a bot.

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: Edited my original post with the relevant part of my code

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a cog that replies to a specific word mentioned. It also has a cooldown to prevent the bot spamming which I find absolutely neccesary to include.

```py
from curses.panel import bottom_panel
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class brilliant(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 60.0, commands.BucketType.member) # Change accordingly
                                                        # rate, per, BucketType
    
    def ratelimit_check(self, message):
        """Returns the ratelimit left"""
        bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(message)
        return bucket.update_rate_limit()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return
        msg = message.content.lower()   
        brilliant = ['brilliant', 'Brilliant', 'brilliant!', 'Brilliant!'] 
        if any(word in msg for word in brilliant):
            retry_after = self.ratelimit_check(message)
            if retry_after is None:
                await message.channel.send("Brilliant!")
                await self.bot.process_commands(message)
            else:
                return

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(brilliant(bot))
```

If you want it in the main file, you can put something a lot simpler:

```py
brilliant = ['brilliant', 'Brilliant', 'brilliant!', 'Brilliant!']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
    return  
  msg = message.content.lower()

  if any(word in msg for word in brilliant):
    await message.channel.send("Brilliant!")
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, this helped a lot! @commands.Cog.listener() was the answer!

Comment: extra kudos for the class brilliant!